# Does reinterpret_cast lead to undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, templates, reinterpret-cast

I have a class template `A` which contains a container of pointers (`T*`):

```
template <typename T>
class A {
public:
   // ... 
private:
   std::vector<T*> data;
};
```

and a bunch of functions like:

```
void f(const A<const T>&);
void g(const A<const T>&);
```

Is it OK to call these functions via a cast from `A<const T>` to `A<T>`?

```
A<double> a;
... 
auto& ac = reinterpret_cast<const A<const double>&>(a);
f(ac);
```

I'm pretty sure that this code has undefined behaviour.

Is it dangerous to use such conversions in real life?

Comment: If it's UB, it is certainly dangerous to use them in real life. This sounds suspiciously like an XY problem, though.

Comment: Relying on UB is always dangerous, even if *"it works in the real world"*. Just think of projects such as Qt-5, Chromium, KDevelop that where broken by gcc6 because the used some `this == nullptr` nonsense.

Comment: @Holt Could be an unchangeable interface.

Comment: You should read section `5.2.10 Reinterpret cast` in the standard: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4582.pdf

Comment: @erip I have updated the question. Do you have suggestions how to address the problem?

Comment: @Holt The same method could be called with both `A<const T>` and `A<T>`. I can't leave only `A<T>` and throw away `A<const T>`, otherwise I loose const-correctness.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As `A<double>` and `A<const double>` are unrelated types, it's actually unspecified (originally I thought undefined) behavior and correspondingly yes it's a bad idea to use in real life: You never know what system(s) or compiler(s) you may port to that change the behavior is strange ways.

Reference:

5.2.10/11:

> An lvalue expression of type T1 can be cast to the type “reference to
>   T2” if an expression of type “pointer to T1” can be explicitly
>   converted to the type “pointer to T2” using a reinterpret_cast. That
>   is, a reference cast reinterpret_cast(x) has the same effect as
>   the conversion *reinterpret_cast(&x) with the built-in & and *
>   operators (and similarly for reinterpret_cast(x)).

So they've redirected us to an earlier section 5.2.10/7:

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of
>   a different type. ... ... Converting a prvalue of type
>   “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are
>   object types and where the alignment requirements of T2 are no
>   stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields the
>   original pointer value. The result of any other such pointer
>   conversion is unspecified.

If `f` and `g` are algorithms that work on containers, the easy solution is to change them to template algorithms that work on ranges (iterator pairs).

Comment: I agree, but I haven't been able to see anything in the standard wrt UB in this instance. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @erip It breaks strict aliasing, right? So even if the layout of the two were the same, it'd be UB anyway.

Comment: @MarkB I still think this is UB under `[basic.lval]/10` (at least if OP goes on to access the parameters).

Comment: @MarkB I was afraid of this. I have updated the question. Could you suggest something on that?

Answer (score 10):

Although the `reinterpret_cast` itself might be unspecified behaviour, attempting to access the parameters once you've done the cast is undefined behaviour.

> `N3337 [basic.lval]/10:`
>   If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined
>
> — the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a type similar (as defined in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type
>   of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or non-
>   static data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate
>   or contained union),
>
> — a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a char or unsigned char type.

Your example is none of the above.

Comment: And calling any non-static member function on the thing violates [class.mfct.non-static]/2, even if it doesn't access class members. Pretty much UB all around if the resulting reference is used in any way.