# Pointer arithmetic using cast to "wrong" type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, pointer-arithmetic

I have an array of structs, and I have a pointer to *a member* of one of those structs.  I would like to know which element of the array contains the member.  Here are two approaches:

```
#include <array>
#include <string>

struct xyz
{
    float x, y;
    std::string name;
};

typedef std::array<xyz, 3> triangle;

// return which vertex the given coordinate is part of
int vertex_a(const triangle& tri, const float* coord)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<const xyz*>(coord) - tri.data();
}

int vertex_b(const triangle& tri, const float* coord)
{
    std::ptrdiff_t offset = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(coord) - reinterpret_cast<const char*>(tri.data());
    return offset / sizeof(xyz);
}
```

Here's a test driver:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    triangle tri{{{12.3, 45.6}, {7.89, 0.12}, {34.5, 6.78}}};
    for (const xyz& coord : tri) {
        std::cout
            << vertex_a(tri, &coord.x) << ' '
            << vertex_b(tri, &coord.x) << ' '
            << vertex_a(tri, &coord.y) << ' '
            << vertex_b(tri, &coord.y) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Both approaches produce the expected results:

```
0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
```

**But are they valid code?**

In particular I wonder if `vertex_a()` might be invoking undefined behavior by casting `float* y` to `xyz*` since the result does not actually point to a `struct xyz`.  That concern led me to write `vertex_b()`, which I think is safe (is it?).

Here's the code generated by GCC 6.3 with -O3:

```
vertex_a(std::array<xyz, 3ul> const&, float const*):
    movq    %rsi, %rax
    movabsq $-3689348814741910323, %rsi ; 0xCCC...CD
    subq    %rdi, %rax
    sarq    $3, %rax
    imulq   %rsi, %rax

vertex_b(std::array<xyz, 3ul> const&, float const*):
    subq    %rdi, %rsi
    movabsq $-3689348814741910323, %rdx ; 0xCCC...CD
    movq    %rsi, %rax
    mulq    %rdx
    movq    %rdx, %rax
    shrq    $5, %rax
```

Comment: That's breaking [the strict aliasing rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) quite badly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Can you clarify?  I think `vertex_b()` does not break strict-aliasing.  And as for `vertex_a()` I wasn't sure, because the pointer is never dereferenced.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no it isn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither is valid per the standard.

---

In `vertex_a`, you're allowed to convert a pointer to `xyz::x` to a pointer to `xyz` because they're [*pointer-interconvertible*](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#compound-4.3):

> Two objects *a* and *b* are *pointer-interconvertible* if [...] one is a standard-layout class object and the other is the first non-static data member of that object [...]
>
> If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer to the other via a `reinterpret_­cast`.

But you can't do the cast from a pointer to `xyz::y` to a pointer to `xyz`. That operation is undefined.

---

In `vertex_b`, you're subtracting two pointers to `const char`. That operation is defined in [[expr.add]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add) as:

> If the expressions `P` and `Q` point to, respectively, elements `x[i]` and `x[j]` of the same array object `x`, the expression `P - Q` has the value `i − j`; otherwise, the behavior is undefined

Your expressions don't point to elements of an array of `char`, so the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Regarding `vertex_b()`, see the standard here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37119041/4323 - it says "If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through [...] other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined [...] - a char or unsigned char type."  I am certain this means that reading a byte from any object after reinterpret_casting to `char*` is valid.  So given that the cast is valid, and reading chars from the resulting `char*` is valid, I think this should satisfy your `[expr.add]` requirement.  What do you think?

Comment: @John None of that turns what you're pointing to into an array of `char`. Since there is no array that these pointers index into, the subtraction isn't defined.

Comment: OK, so what you're saying is that arithmetic on two char pointers is never OK if the objects they point to were not originally typed as char.  Is that right?  And you're saying this produces UB?  That would be pretty surprising given how common this sort of thing is in networking code (which of course is the same sort of code that takes advantage of the right to cast anything to char* in the first place).

Comment: Also, do you have any alternative implementation that you think is completely legal?

Comment: @John Not just originally typed as char, but char *array*. The wording requires an array.

Comment: @Barry: Both C and C++ existed and were in wide use before the standards were written.  The ability to treat objects in C, and PODS in C++, as sequences of character-type values has *always* been fundamental to both languages.  Since the authors of the C Standard explicitly recognize that it does not mandate everything necessary to make an implementation be useful for any purpose, and the C++ Standard relies upon key aspects of the C Standard, anyone wanting to produce a *useful* implementation must support such behaviors whether or not the exact wording of the Standard would mandate support.

Comment: @supercat I don't know what you guys want. The question is asking what the standard says, I am telling you what the standard, quite clearly and unambiguously, says: subtracting arbitrary char pointers is undefined.

Comment: @Barry: Unless I'm misreading things, the pointers both identify bytes within the same array object.  If `xyz` were a PODS, the byte representation of an array of `xyz` is the concatenation of the byte representations of the `xyz`s therein.  While the presence of a `string` within `xyz` would mean it's not a PODS, the principle that `(char*)(ptr+x)==((char*)ptr)+x*sizeof *ptr` should still hold.

Comment: @supercat That's not how the C++ object model works.

Comment: @Barry: The C++ object model certainly allows for non-PODS objects to contain pointers or other links to objects which in turn contain links back to those non-PODS objects, in Unspecified fashion.  If the `sizeof` operator doesn't specify the stride of arrays of non-PODS objects, what does the indicated value mean?

Comment: `char[3*sizeof(xyz)];` in combination with appropriately adjusted placement new (for simplicity let's consider byte alignment covered already), shouldn't this then suffice to comply with the standard (word by word)?

Comment: Oh, my, even simpler: couldn't we just cast both pointers to `uintptr_t` to get the difference? This is legal, and as both pointers originate from contigous memory, the difference should be meaningful...

Comment: @Aconcagua: The only guarantee about `uintptr_t` is that converting a pointer to `uintptr_t` will yield a number that, when converted back to a pointer, will compare equal to the original.  Although many implementations will guarantee that `(uintptr_t)(p+i) == ((uintptr)p) + (i*sizeof(*p))`, the Standard does not guarantee such behavior, nor even define a testable means (e.g a `__STDC_LINEAR_POINTERS` macro) by which implementations can promise it.

Comment: @supercat So in the end: It is totally legal, but if it works as desired is implementation defined. In other words: No undefined, but unspecified behaviour, so in the sense of the question, valid code at least...

Comment: @Aconcagua: Many implementations--probably 90%+--define the behavior the same way, but there is no "machine-readable" way of identifying the exceptions.

Comment: @supercat Point is: It might not be *fully portable* any more, but at least it is *valid*...

Comment: @Aconcagua: If code relies upon platforms to define behaviors a certain way, but will compile cleanly on conforming implementations where it won't work, such code will be valid on implementations that define the behaviors they need and invalid on those that don't.  Nothing in the Standard should in any way imply that a non-portable program that relies upon Undefined Behavior is in any way "invalid", unless one believes that the phrase "non-portable or erroneous" means "erroneous" even when applied to non-portable programs.

Comment: @Aconcagua: To be sure, the notion that "non-portable or erroneous" is synonymous with "erroneous' seems to be contagious among implementation writers who are more concerned with how well their compiler can process portable C programs for that can be done in portable C, rather than in how well the compiler would be able to perform tasks (including those not possible in portable C) using code written to exploit the target platform.

Answer (score 4):

`vertex_a` indeed breaks the strict aliasing rule (none of your `float`s are valid `xyz`s, and in 50% of your example they're not even at the start of an `xyz` even if there's no padding).

`vertex_b` relies on, shall we say, *creative* interpretation of the standard. Though your cast to `const char*` is sound, performing arithmetic with it around the rest of the array is a little more dodgy. Historically I've concluded that this kind of thing has undefined behaviour, because "the object" in this context is the `xyz`, not the array. However, I'm leaning towards others' interpretation nowadays that this will always work, and wouldn't expect anything else in practice.

Comment: and I've utterly failed to find the references I was looking for, but I'll keep trying

Comment: I thought strict aliasing only applies if the pointer is dereferenced (and in my case it is not).  Was I wrong about that?

Answer (score 3):

`vertex_b` is completely fine. You only maybe need to refine `return offset / sizeof(xyz);` since you're dividing `std::ptrdiff_t` with `std::size_t` and implicitly casting the result into `int`.
By book, this behavior is implementation defined. `std::ptrdiff_t` is signed and `std::size_t` unsigned and result of division might be larger than `INT_MAX` (very unlikely) with huge array size on some platforms/compilers.

To cast away your worries, you can put `assert()`s and/or `#error`s which check `PTRDIFF_MIN`, `PTRDIFF_MAX`, `SIZE_MAX`, `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`, but I personally would not bother so much.

Comment: What about `vertex_a()`?  It was suggested that it breaks strict aliasing, but I don't see how because it does not dereference the pointer.

Comment: `vertex_a` is wrong if `coord` can point to member `y` of `xyz`. The main idea behind pointer arithmetic, since it appeared (in C), is to point to elements, not arbitrary memory location (these are equal for one byte element size). And `coord` may not point to start of `xyz`, you're even allowing a check for any value of `coord`.

Comment: Memory alignment in this case is broken if multiple of required alignment is not equal to `float` size. While many CPUs will allow you to store this address into CPU register and will not produce error until you try to read or write to it, there's no such guarantee. Some CPUs (microcontrollers) might even not have first N lower bits of address register at all due to design simplification and might not even have instruction to insert such an address into register because that instruction will probably not have the first N lower bits also.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a more robust approach would involve changing the type signature to `xyz::T*` (`T` is a template argument so you can take `xyz::x` or `xyz::y` as needed) instead of `float*`

Then you can use `offsetof(struct xyz,T)` to confidently compute the location of the start of the struct in a way that should be more resilient to future changes in its definition.

Then the rest follows as you are currently doing: once you have a pointer to the start of the struct finding its offset in the array is a valid pointer subtraction.

There is some pointer nastiness involved. But this is an approach that is used. e.g. see the container_of() macro in the linux kernel.
https://www.linuxjournal.com/files/linuxjournal.com/linuxjournal/articles/067/6717/6717s2.html

Comment: In some cases I only have a pointer to the member, and don't know its name.  I only know the address.