# Undefined behavior of member function call through wrong pointer type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, strict-aliasing, reinterpret-cast

Consider the program

```
#include<iostream>

struct A {
};

struct B {
    void f() { std::cout << "Hello world!\n"; };
};

static_assert(alignof(A) == alignof(B));

int main() {
    A a;
    reinterpret_cast<B*>(&a)->f();
};
```

Note that the value of `a` is never read or modified in the sense of the aliasing rule, as far as I can tell.

I am pretty sure that the above has undefined behavior, because I am trying to call `f` on an object of wrong type. But what passage in the standard actually says that?

Comment: The standard quoted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37119041/514235) should be answering your question. `N3337 [basic.lval]/10: If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined`

Comment: @iammilind The aliasing rule quoted in the answer is actually not answering the question, because I am explicitly not accessing any value of the object, but the comment under the answer regarding [class.mfct.non-static]/2 is what I was looking for.

Comment: I'd say the questions listed above are unrelated, but AFAIR similar question has been asked, maybe not even once.