# why I can call function defined in derived class using a base object (non-virtual)?

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;

class Base
{
        public:
        void print(){printf("base\n");}
};

class Derived:public Base
{
        public:
        void print(){printf("derived\n");}
};

int main()
{
    Base* bptr= new Base;
    Derived* pptr=static_cast<Derived*> (bptr);
    pptr->print();
    return 0;
}
```

The above program print out "derived" on Linux.  My question is that since Base object does have the derived version of print function, why downcasting the pointer make it able to find the function in derived class ? what is the mechanism behind it?

Comment: Undefined Behavior is undefined. Anything could happen, including seeming to work.

Comment: Your code has explicitly called `Derived::print()`, since `pptr` is of type `Derived *`.    If you remove the `static_cast` the code will not compile, since `bptr` does not point at a `Derived`.   The behaviour is undefined since you have explicitly, by using `static_cast` forced the compiler to allow `pptr` to have a value that is not actually the address of a `Derived`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are (in general) not allowed to do this:

```
Derived* pptr=static_cast<Derived*> (bptr);
```

In your simple example, nothing will go wrong - I'm not "a language lawyer", but I do believe there is no undefined behavior in your simple case. (Edit: per Peter's comment, the function call through pptr is actually undefined behavior.)

Should your derived class have a different size than your base class, and should the method you call access some members that are actually not there (because only the body of Base is physically there), you would be in undefined behavior land. Same goes for if you were to delete your Base class through a pointer to Derived, when there is actually only the body of Base there.

As for why the print method of Derived gets called - that's simple. By explicitly casting to Derived in the line I mentioned above, you have explicitly said - treat this pointer as if it were a pointer to Derived; so the compiler does just that. You are calling the method print on a pointer to Derived - that means the print method of Derived will be called, and there is nothing more to say. (There would be, if it were a virtual method, but it is not.)

To sum it up - don't manually cast pointers to types of which the target object is actually not; if you do, you're responsible for what happens next.

Comment: The call of `pptr->print()` has undefined behaviour, since `pptr` does not point at an actual instance of `Derived`.    The `static_cast` does not have undefined behaviour in itself, but does cause `pptr->print()` to have undefined behaviour since it forces the compiler to allow `pptr` to be initialised to point at something that is not a `Derived`.

Comment: Can you elaborate/provide a reference for that? Again, I genuinely don't know - I'm currently under the impression that this would be fine for Similar Types (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37119041/1732555 ), but as I said, I'm not sure.

Comment: You're assuming "similar types" in the standard means something it doesn't.   `Derived` and `Base` in the OP's question do not meet the definition of "similar types".

Comment: Ok, I will refresh my memory on that, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When non-virtual lookup is being used (as in your example), the compiler simply examines the type making the call. In your case the call is being made through a pointer-to-Derived and so Derived::print is called. The fact that the object is actually of type Base simply does not enter into the name resolution (although it would not surprise me if a sufficiently finicky compiler would pick up on this particular example).