# Safe usage of `reinterpret_cast`

Tags: c++

If I have an aggregate of integral types and I want to create a instance of it with random, is `reinterpret_cast` being used here safe?

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto random() -> T {
  static auto random_device = std::random_device{};
  static auto generator     = std::mt19937(random_device());
  static auto distribution  = std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint8_t>{};

  auto bytes = std::array<std::uint8_t, sizeof(T)>{};

  for (auto i = std::size_t{0}; i < bytes.size(); ++i) {
    bytes[i] = distribution(generator);
  }

  return *reinterpret_cast<T *>(bytes.data());
}
```

Comment: Consider using [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast). If `T` is trivially copyable then it's safe.

Comment: Why not write a specialized function for your aggregate, that properly sets all members or elements to a random value?

Comment: This is not safe, the strict aliasing rule violation. Rework it in the opposite cast from T* to byte* or char*, that should with static_cast.

Comment: @user207421 Why have you removed the deference?

Comment: For C++23 there is [std::start_lifetime_as](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/start_lifetime_as)

Comment: I should probably mention that i'm using GCC-10 so `bit_cast` is no available

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I can, but it's repetitive so I don't want to do it

Comment: @PepijnKramer GCC-10 so no C++23 for me

Comment: Most of the repetition can be abstracted out into classes or functions, together with overloads. But on the plus-side, you'll have something that is safe, portable, and can't be misused (there's nothing in your code stopping someone from using `random<std::string>()` which will not give a very good result).

Comment: @UyHà If you read [std::bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) documentation you will find you can easily provide your own implementation for the time being. Also if something is repetitive but correct either do it or provide a function (writing good code is not always about writing the least amount of code).

Comment: The big issue with `std::reinterpret_cast` it is usually incorrect. During code review for me this is usually a red flag. Casting will NOT start lifetime of objects (constructors will not be called) so it is too easy to end up with an object that is not in a valid state.

Comment: This is Unspecified Behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37118638/1387438

Comment: Another possible choice is `std::as_writable_bytes` in c++20. But if you don't have access to `bit_cast` it is likely that you don't have access to `std::as_writable_bytes` either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>`Firstly this will not compile in the general case. You cannot` reinterpret_cast`into an arbitrary type. If`T` is not a pointer type or an integral type this will not compile.</s>

To fix this you probably want to return

```
return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(bytes.data());
```

But do not do that either. If `T` is not `((un)signed) char` or `std::byte` this is undefined behavior.

The correct way to implement such a function is to first make sure the target type `T` satisfies the criteria to do this. I will over-restrict it by requiring that it is trivial:

```
decltype(auto) get_mt19937() {
    static auto random_device = std::random_device{};
    static auto generator     = std::mt19937(random_device());
    return generator;
}

template <typename T>
auto random() -> T {

    static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<T>, "T must be trivial");

    // This is bad. It will instantiate a new mt19937 engine for each type `T`.
    //static auto random_device = std::random_device{};
    //static auto generator     = std::mt19937(random_device());
    
    auto& generator = get_mt19937();

    // no need to static
    auto distribution  = std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned char>{};

    auto return_val = T{};
    // reinterpret_cast'ing to std::uint8_t* might not be legal
    auto* bytes = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&return_val);

    for (auto i = std::size_t{0}; i < sizeof(T); ++i) {
        bytes[i] = distribution(generator);
    }


    return return_val;
}
```

Comment: My post got modified by someone and its semantic changed, the return statement should be ` return *reinterpret_cast<T *>(bytes.data());`

Answer (score 2):

For a generic type `T`, this may not be not safe.
According to the [c++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), a `reinterpret_cast` is allowed if:

> 5. Any object pointer type T1* can be converted to another object
>    pointer type cv T2*. This is exactly equivalent to static_cast<cv
>    T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(expression)) (which implies that if T2's
>    alignment requirement is not stricter than T1's, the value of the
>    pointer does not change and conversion of the resulting pointer back
>    to its original type yields the original value). In any case, the
>    resulting pointer may only be dereferenced safely if allowed by the
>    type aliasing rules (see below).

So, you can do the cast from `*std::uint8_t` to `*T`. But the problem is, when can you dereference the resulting pointer to `T`?
Not for every type `T` is this allowed.
The [same page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) says that you can dereference to a AliasedType `T` if:

> AliasedType is std::byte, (since C++17) char, or unsigned char: this
> permits examination of the object representation of any object as an
> array of bytes.

So, if you restrict the use of your routine to the `std::byte`, `char`, or `unsigned char` (as mentioned above in the second quote), yes, you can then safely dereference the pointer in the `return` statement and your function should be safe.

But, you should rather consider to use [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) to store a generic raw-memory buffer.

Comment: `to the types T mentioned above` the only type mentioned above is `std::uint8_t`, right? You also mention `std::byte, char and unsigned char`. So only std::uint8_t, std::byte, char and unsigned char are valid T? It's hard for me to clarify "mentioned above".

Comment: `you can do the cast from *std::uint8_t to *T` well, yes but `which implies that if T2's alignment requirement is not stricter than T1's`. When T2 alignment requirements are stricter, the value of the resulting pointer is unspecified. I do not think it is that safe. https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#static.cast-14

Comment: @KamilCuk about the alignement: sure, that's what I quote from the c++ reference. I think, it does not apply though to the simple conversion to ```std::byte```, ```char``` or ```unsigned char```. It would matter for the other aliasing detailed in the reference.

Comment: For some reason, some user modified my post and change its semantic, it's supposed to be `return *reinterpret_cast<T *>(bytes.data());`

Comment: @UyHà I modified the answer according to the return type of your function