# Is memcpy-ing a struct into a buffer of uint8_ts and reinterpret-casting it back to struct undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct A
{
    float a = 1;
    float b = 2;
    float c = 3;
};

struct B
{
    float a = 1;
    float b = 2;
};

int main()
{
    uint8_t buffer[5 * sizeof(float)];

    A a0;
    memcpy(buffer, &a0, 3 * sizeof(float));
    A a1 = *reinterpret_cast<A*>(buffer);
    std::cout << a1.a << " " << a1.b << " " << a1.c << '\n';

    int offset = 3;

    B b0;
    memcpy(buffer + offset, &b0, 2 * sizeof(float));
    B b1 = *reinterpret_cast<B*>(buffer + offset);
    std::cout << b1.a << " " << b1.b << " " << '\n';
}
```

Does the code above have any undefined behaviour? It seems to work fine.

Comment: Use `sizeof (A)` or `sizeof a0` instead of multiple of `sizeof (float)`.

Comment: While unlikely in this case, please read this: [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Comment: Also note that `memcpy` only works for trivial structures, like the ones shown.

Comment: As for your question and how to improve it, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: What's the use case? The "casting" part is creating a copy, which the compiler will likely implement using `memcpy`.

Comment: Based on this SO answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37118426/1387438 `reinterpret_cast` on unrelated types is Unspecified Behavior and then when using value it is Undefined Behavior.
When ignoring UB, main problem with your code is alignment issue which will lead to crash on ARM processors (`float` must be aligned there).

Comment: If you do `sizeof(A)` instead of `3*sizeof(float)` then you are good. If your `std::uint8_t` is `unsigned char`, then you are excepted from undefined behaviour, as described in [type aliasing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)

Comment: In addition to above comments: the alignment of your buffer might be wrong.