# istream_iterator behavior misunderstanding

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, istream, istream-iterator

The goal is to read *16 bit signed integers* from a *binary* file. First, I open the file as an ***ifstream***, then I would like to copy each numbers into a vector using ***istream_iterator*** and the ***copy*** algorithm.
I dont' understand what's wrong with this snippet:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::string filename("test.bin");

    std::ifstream is(filename);
    if (!is) {
        std::cerr << "Error while opening input file\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    std::noskipws(is);
    std::vector<int16_t> v;
    std::copy(
        std::istream_iterator<int16_t>(is),
        std::istream_iterator<int16_t>(),
        std::back_inserter(v)
    );

    //v is still empty
}
```

This code produces no error but the vector remains empty after the call to ***std::copy***. Since I'm opening the file in the standard input mode ("textual" mode), I was expecting ***istream_iterator*** to work even if the file is binary. Of course there's something I'm missing about the behavior of this class.

Comment: When i n doubt, get stupid. Replace the `std::copy` with a loop and print out what's read.

Comment: Reading a binary file as text usually doesn't work. if the first value in the file is 27715 stored in binary, 0x6C43, the stream iterator is going to see it as `mC` or `Cm`, depending on the endian, and won't be able to convert it to a number due to a general lack of digits.

Comment: " Since I'm opening the file in the standard input mode ("textual" mode), I was expecting istream_iterator to work even if the file is binary." I think you fundamentally misunderstand both what "binary/text mode" and "binary/text file" mean. The former is a set of rules for deciding how to *interpret the contents of* the file. The latter doesn't *really* mean anything, but conventionally it describes a general approach to *giving semantics to* the file. If you try to interpret the file contents in a way that doesn't match how it was intended to be understood, *of course* it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, to read a binary file with `ifstream`, you need to open the file in `binary` mode, not text mode (the default). Otherwise, read operations may mis-interpret linebreak bytes and translate them between platform encodings (ie, CRLF->LF, or vice versa), thus corrupting your binary data.

Second, `istream_iterator` uses `operator>>`, which reads and parses *formatted text* by default, which is not what you want when reading a binary file. You need to use [`istream::read()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) instead. However, there is no iterator wrapper for that (but you can write your own if needed).

Try this instead:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::string filename = "test.bin";

    std::ifstream is(filename, std::ifstream::binary);
    if (!is) {
        std::cerr << "Error while opening input file\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::vector<int16_t> vec;
    int16_t value;

    while (is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value))) {
        // swap value's endian, if needed...
        vec.push_back(value);
    }

    // use vec as needed...

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, if you really want to use `istream_iterator` for a binary file, then you would have to write a custom class/struct to wrap `int16_t`, and then define an `operator>>` for that type to call `read()`, eg:

```cpp
struct myInt16_t {
    int16_t value; 
    operator int16_t() const { return value; }
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, myInt16_t &v) {
    if (is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&v.value), sizeof(v.value))) {
        // swap v.value's endian, if needed...
    }
    return is;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::string filename = "test.bin";

    std::ifstream is(filename, std::ifstream::binary);
    if (!is) {
        std::cerr << "Error while opening input file\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::noskipws(is);
    std::vector<int16_t> vec;
    std::copy(
        std::istream_iterator<myInt16_t>(is),
        std::istream_iterator<myInt16_t>(),
        std::back_inserter(vec)
    );

    // use vec as needed...

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Since I'm opening the file in the standard input mode ("textual" mode), I was expecting istream_iterator to work even if the file is binary.

You conceptually have it the wrong way around. Since the file "is binary"<sup>1</sup>, you should *not* expect `istream_iterator` to work *even though* the file is opened "in text mode"<sup>2</sup>. The file's format determines what you can do with it; no tool can read the "numbers formatted as human-readable text" from the file *unless the file is actually intended to be read that way*. Your file is, presumably, intended to be read as "pairs of bytes, each of which represents a 16-bit numeric value", so you need tools that are compatible with that format. The file *mode* is only a small piece of the puzzle.

To iterate over the file meaningfully, you need to open it in binary mode (to avoid corruption on Windows platforms) *and also* use a tool that is capable of interpreting binary data in the way that you want. You also need to ensure that you are thinking about the data properly. Trying to use things like `noskipws` makes no sense because *the data doesn't have a concept of whitespace, because it doesn't represent text*.

1. This doesn't really mean anything strictly speaking; but typically, saying that a file "is binary" suggests that the file contents are **not** intended to be human-readable, and that numeric values are represented as they would be in computer memory, i.e. *directly in base 256*, and **not** using the bytes to represent text that in turn uses Arabic numerals, `.` symbols etc. to represent a number.
2. What it means to open a file "in text mode" depends on both the language you are using and the platform. In many languages (including C and C++), it has very little effect on Windows (basically just translating CR-LF sequences in place) and none (at least, last I checked) on Linux-like platforms. In some (like Python 3.x), it automatically brings in the machinery to convert bytes to objects representing actual text, actually using an encoding rather than pretending that bytes "are characters" (they are not).

Comment: `no instance of constructor "std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>::istreambuf_iterator [with _CharT=int16_t, _Traits=std::char_traits<int16_t>]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (std::ifstream)` --> I get this compiler error when trying to use ***istreambuf_iterator***.

Comment: Looks like I'm rustier than I thought. Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644616/read-a-binary-file-into-a-stdvectoruint16-t-instead-of-stdvectorchar help?

Comment: Yes it works fine, but I was looking to a solution concerning ***istreambuf_iterator***, but it seems it can only be used with char types

Comment: I edited to remove the incorrect code, because it's unsalvagable. Left the relevant discussion.